# iOS Simulator phonegap/cordova webkit inspector

Tags: web-development, ios

I know that Safari currently supports developer tools for the iOS Simulator. However each time you need to restart the simulator you have to go back to safari and reselect the device and reopen the developer tools.

I have found http://www.debuggap.com/ but it just isn't as full featured as I would prefer (i.e. inability to make changes to the DOM and CSS)

Are there other tools for this that accomplish the same task?

Comment: To clarify, do you want a tool to automatically enable the tools in the Simulator or another tool that isn't the iOS Simulator?

Comment: using the iOS Simulator is a necessity.